# ViewModel of 3 models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

Hello am using MVC4 am trying to use viewmodel so that i can access to the data  of 3 model...

I want to show list of following information:(Project Name , Supplier Name, Supplier answer)

here my code:

```
public class Projects
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class SubmitedProjects
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierAnswerr { get; set; 
}

public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; 
}
```

My try of view model :

```
public class ModelInfo
  {
    public ProjectEntry oProjects { get; set; }
    public SubmittedProject oSubmitedProjects { get; set; }

  }
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult MProjects ( )
    {

       SubmittedProjectContext d = new SubmittedProjectContext();
       ProjectContext ds = new ProjectContext();
       List <ModelInfo> r = new List <ModelInfo>();
       ModelInfo rr = new ModelInfo();

         rr.oSubmitedProjects=new SubmittedProject();
         rr.oProjects=new Projects();
         r.Add(rr);
         return View(r);
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You want to have data of these 3 class in view right?

Comment: yes all of them in one VIEW

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show list of following information: (Project Name , Supplier Name, Supplier answer)

Then your view model class should look like this:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to use multiple projects in one view:

```
public class MultipleProjectsViewModel
{
    public IList<ProjectViewModel> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you build up your view model in your controller, based on whatever information you need to base it on.

Remember, the *view model* models the *view*. If you need that information in your view, put those properties in your view model. Your view model is *not supposed to be directly tied to your domain/business entities*. It is a different thing that serves a different purpose. Get into the habit of separating them.

Comment: why MultipleProjectsViewModel ...? i did not understand?! I need to show all  SubmitedProjects in my SubmitedProjectsContext.

Comment: can you show me how the controller will look like ?

Comment: No, I can't, because I don't know what your logic is. You just need to instantiate a new view model (one of the above classes) and build up the information based on the objects in your database, then pass the view model to the view. Try Googling "view models in asp.net mvc." The point is you *do not pass objects from your database to your view*, you create *view model* objects and use those.

Comment: see am bit confuse ... why you are not using my classes in your solutions ...as i know that we use viewmodel to integrate 2 classes or more together ?! see my try ..i tried to do that !

Comment: I am using classes. Those things up there are classes. You don't use view models to just bundle data entities together, they should be *completely independent* of your EF entities (i.e. hold no reference to them) and they should contain *just the information you need for your view*. If that information *comes from* an EF entity, that's fine but it shouldn't *be* an EF entity. I'm not sure how many different ways I can say this but, again, I think what you need to do is read up on view models and the reasons they are used.

Answer (score -1):

I would just make a ViewModel for that page, fill the properties of that ViewModel and pass it to the view

e.g.

```
public class ExampleViewModel{
   public string ProjectName { get; set; }
   public string SupplierName { get; set; }
   public string SupplierAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

in the controller

```
ExampleViewModel evm = new ExampleViewModel();
evm.ProjectName = "Name";
evm.SupplierName = "Supplier";
evm.SupplierAnswer = "Answer";
return View(evm);
```

Comment: this is likely the right way to go. I guess you could use automapper to deal with mapping it all up.

Comment: assuming those classes are your entities (from EF or some other ORM) you can just load the data in those entities and instantiate the ViewModel properties with the properties from your entities like `evm.ProjectName = projects.ProjectName`

Comment: mmm oky I try this will pass only one projects ...how i list all of them ?

Comment: pass a List<ExampleViewModel> to the view, you will need to change the `@model ExampleViewModel`at the top of the view to, i think, `@model System.Collections.Generic.List<ExampleViewModel>` or `@model System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ExampleViewModel>`, after that you can iterate through the list in the view

Comment: oky i got that too  using @model List<projectName.Models.Myviewmodel>.......But now using your code we create new one ...i dont want to create new ones ...i want to list them as I have them in my database ..!?

Comment: seeing the classes in your question is assume you are using Entity Framework if so you can load in everything using that. more info on Entity Framework can be found here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723)

Comment: @Ant ofcourse it looks similar, i'm not going to make a viewmodel with properties that aren't necessary. I copied the names from the askers post and removed his typo, i didn't copy&paste it from you if that's what you're insinuating

Comment: That's not what I'm insinuating. What I'm insinuating is that your answer doesn't add any value (I don't consider an example demonstrating how to instantiate an object and assign to properties to be particularly valuable).